# WCF Windows Authenticated Endpoint

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I have a sample wcf service,I want to one of endpoint is windows authenticated security ,My Config is like that ,In iis both windows and anynomous authentication is enabled.But I can call my endpoint directly,there is no user info my call code?What I am missing?I want to define multiple endpoints which can be accesible different authentication type for that reason I cannot close anonymous authentication.

My second question is,can  endpoint work for specific user in windows authentication?

> ```
> ServiceReference1.Service1Client sclient = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
>
>        var x= sclient.GetData(1);
> ```
>
> ```
>       </security>
>     </binding>
>   </wsHttpBinding>
> </bindings>
> <services>
>   <service  name="Service">
>     <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsHttpBindingConfig" contract="IService">
>       <!--<identity>
>         <userPrincipalName value="xxxxxxx" />
>       </identity>-->
>     </endpoint>
>   </service>
> </services>
> <behaviors
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should edit your contract name. It usually under your webservice package like this *WebServiceName*.IService